# Поздравляем MaxU с достижением 100К репутации!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи, поздравление

Поздравляем [@MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu) с достижением этого (большого, по меркам ruSO) значения. Спасибо за Ваш вклад в развитие сообщества! Мы это ценим!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поздравляю! :-)

Comment: Поздравляю **MaxU** с достижением 100k!  Вы, как один из первой пятерки космонавтов, которых  помнят, и Вас будут помнить, пока жив ресурс. Потом будут и другие перешагнувшие этот рубеж, но Вы были одним из первых. А это наиболее ценно. Тем более видно со стороны, что отвечать на вопросы Вам доставляет удовольствие и чувствуется высокий профессионализм.

Comment: Поздравляю!!!!!

Comment: Поздравляю! Решения в ответах MaxU, особенно по Pandas, стали для меня эталонными. При ~1.5m просмотров, несомненно, и многим другим удалось почерпнуть для себя много полезного.

Comment: А почему @ValdD никто не поздравлял?

Comment: @Danis Все были так ошеломлены, что... :)

Comment: Наши поздравления!

Comment: @Danis, [поздравляли](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32380198#32380198) просто в чате :)

Comment: @Grundy Вот это раньше чатик был! Жаль, не застал те времена:(

Answer (score 15):

## Поздравляю тоже!!!

Участник @MaxU действительно заслужил 100k огромным количеством полезных ответов и желаю ему:

- Не останавливаться на достигнутом, а заработать и <s>256k</s> 200k а потом и 1M!!! ;)
- И дальше пополнять нашу базу знаний (которая как коммунизм, [как известно](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56091075)) и помогать людям.

Answer (score 9):

Очень рад!!!! ОГРОМНАЯ БЛАГОДАРНОСТЬ MaxU. Помню его ответы. Быстро и Качественно.  100К - это круто!
Искренне желаю  дальнейших успехов !!!!!
Даешь 1М!!!

Answer (score 4):

От лица проекта поздравляю вас с достижением этой знаменательной вехи! Большое спасибо за ваш вклад в русскоязычную базу знаний. Ваши ответы выручали много раз и меня лично. Причем как данные в моих вопросах, так и уже имеющиеся на нашем сайте и других сайтах сети Stack Exchange!